# Ada GPS IDE Compiler error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ada

Trying to get GtkAda to work. Didn't compile the lib myself, had  a lot of problems and finally I found a precompiled library on the internet. Of course GPS didn't find it even after adding it to my path...

So I added it manually to my project and GPS began the compilation. It is just a simple example to see if everything works. Just beginning to learn programming.

```
WITH Gtk.Main ;          
USE Gtk.Main ;
WITH Gtk.Window ;        
USE Gtk.Window ;
WITH Gtk.Enums ;         
USE Gtk.Enums ;

PROCEDURE MaFenetre IS
win : Gtk_window ;
BEGIN
Init ;
Gtk_New(win,Window_Popup) ;
win.show ;
Main ;
END MaFenetre ;
```

Which gave me this error:

> gnatlink /Users/laurentlutgen/GPS/mafenetre.ali -o
>   /Users/laurentlutgen/GPS/mafenetre
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_ada_c_enum_value_size", referenced from:
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   "_pango_tab_array_new", referenced from:
>         *pango*_tabs__pango_new in pango-tabs.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status   gnatlink: error when calling /usr/local/gnat/bin/gcc
>   gnatmake: *** link failed.
>   [2013-08-01 21:16:46] process exited with
>   status 4 (elapsed time: 09.38s)

The list of files the compiler complains about is quite long so.

Anyone an idea how to solve this.

I use the last version of gnat (2013) from AdaCore for MacOS X. I use MacOS 10.8.
The GtkAda library is xadalib 2012.

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: flyx [is working on](https://github.com/flyx/gps-osx) building GPS (a Gtk & Ada application) to use the native Quartz display system rather than XQuartz. Might be useful ...

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, `gnatlink` does not get passed the libraries needed to link against. You said that you added GtkAda to your project manually. By doing this, you probably missed all the linker options specified in the `*.gpr` file of GtkAda, so your binary does not get linked against the GTK+ library.

I suggest you try to get GPS to find the installed GtkAda project file. You can do this by setting `ADA_PROJECT_PATH` before launching GPS. If GtkAda is located in GNAT GPL's default path, it looks like this:

```
$ export ADA_PROJECT_PATH="/usr/local/gnat/lib/gnat"
$ gps
```

You said you're using a precompiled binary you found on the internet. Are you aware that GtkAda is bundled with the GNAT GPL compiler? You should use that, unless you want to use gtk-quartz as backend (which doesn't require X11). If that's the case, you may find the [instructions I wrote](https://github.com/flyx/gps-osx) for compiling GPS with gtk-quartz helpful (as Simon already noted).

If you want, you can try my [GPS port to OSX](http://flyx.github.io/gps-osx/). By default, it is able to load the `*.gpr` files bundled with GNAT GPL. On the [Usage](http://flyx.github.io/gps-osx/usage.html) page, you find instructions of how to change the `ADA_PROJECT_PATH` if you installed your GNAT somewhere else.

For further help, you should post the `*.gpr` file of your project.

**Edit:**

I stand corrected: GtkAda is in fact not included in the GNAT GPL distribution for whatever reason. As XmlAda is included as project to link against, I was sure GtkAda was too, but it isn't; so using XAdaLib seems to be the easiest option. You have to point `ADA_PROJECT_PATH` to the installation directory of XAdaLib instead of the usual GNAT one to be able to use GtkAda.

Comment: I tried your instructions to build gps against quartz: worked so far until this: jhbuild shell < build-gps.sh.  Where do I find this? mdfind/spotlight didn't find it anywhere.  I have tried your bundled app together with the modification ADA_PROJECT_PATH and using the GtkAda template my little test now fails with the message: gprbuild: "mafenetre.adb" is not a source of any project. Same for X11 gps. I have defined a main file and my project has a name. So perhaps some progress. Probably hiding some other problems. BTW How do I add an empty to this comment thing? Return posts my comment!? Thx

Comment: `build-gps.sh` is part of my git repository where the README is located in, you'd have to clone it first. However, if you've come that far without errors, you should already have a working GtkAda installation in `~/gtk/inst/lib/gnat`, and you don't really need to compile gps. Concerning your current error, you should have a `for Source_Dirs use ("src");` or something in your project file. Check whether your actual source file is located in that directory and is named `mafenetre.adb` - the error suggests that it is not.

Comment: The minimal `.gpr` would be this - in the same directory as `mafenetre.adb`.
`with "gtkada";
project Mf is
   for Main use ("mafenetre.adb");
end Mf;`

Comment: I think I have messed up my path and I don't know what else. cleaning up everything. Perhaps it works otherwise it was my last try with gtkada for now. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know none of the GPL'ed GNATs from AdaCore for x86 have the capability to *generate* 64-bit code. I think I read something to that effect somewhere but cannot remember where.

---

The issue also came up in the Ada-port of Doom3, so if you can find him he might know for sure.

Comment: For Mac OS X they are all configured with `--build=x86_64-apple-darwin*`, so they don't have the capacity to generate *32-bit* code.

Comment: Didn't know that; thanks for the info. (I don't have/use a Mac, so I've never had opportunity to play with its GNAT implementation.)

Comment: If I have the time I will try to compile this Doom3 project. If I get the same error it is a problem with 32/64 bit otherwise it is my gps/gnat installation which is bugged. First have to solve the new problem: gprbuild: "mafenetre.adb" is not a source of any project. Perhaps this hides the original one.